# Sequentially transform multiple XSLT in Pyspark

Tags: xml, azure, pyspark, xslt, databricks

I am currently working on a Databricks notebook that will load multiple xml files and needs to apply an xslt transformation to each one of them.
The xml files are pretty complex and after the transformation they contain data for multiple tables.
I created an XSLT file that performs the transformations (using XSLT 2.0).
My issue is that i need to apply these transformations to 30-40 files each time and using pysaxon on pyspark i can only do it sequentially.

Is there a way to perform thoses transformations in parralel ? I tried putting the transformation bit of code in an UDF but that made my clusters python kernel unresponsive as starting one pysaxon processor for each row must be memory heavy.

Here is my code currently which processes it sequentially

```
xlst = spark.read.text(file_path_xslt,wholetext=True) # We load the entire xslt in one string
stringxslt = xlst.head()[0]
listOfTransformedXML = []
with PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
    xsltproc = proc.new_xslt_processor()
    xsltproc.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_text=stringxslt)
    for file in dbutils.fs.ls(pathToADLSStorage):
        data = spark.read.text(file[0])
        stringxml = data.head()[0]
        document = proc.parse_xml(xml_text=stringxml)
        xsltproc.set_source(xdm_node=document)
        output2 = xsltproc.transform_to_string()
        stringforxmlobj = output2.replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>","")#remove the encoding string otherwise we cant read the xml into an object
        listOfTransformedXML.append(stringforxmlobj)
```

Thanks a lot for your help and time

I managed to speed the entire process up by making the notebook process 1 file at a time and the file name being a parameter and putting all of it in an ADF but my guess is that this is pretty cost heavy as one notebook per file is gonna increase the overhead.

EDIT :

Following comments from Martin and Parfait I have adapted Saxon's example to run on multiple threads but the issue i run into is that it seems like it's still running them sequentially as when i try to process 3 files concurrently it takes as much time as if i processed them separately.

here is my updated code, i have added a semaphore to write result strings to an array.
but running this code on my cluster creates 2 jobs on 1 executor. From what I have read this is expected as threads only run on the master and for that to be spread to other nodes I would need to use RDD and lambdas ?

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter, node, compiledStyleSheet):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.counter = counter
    self.name = name
    self.node = node
    self.xslt_executable = compiledStyleSheet

def run(self):
    print ("Starting " + self.name)
    run_transform(self.name, self.counter, self.node, self.xslt_executable)
    print ("Exiting " + self.name)

def run_transform(threadName, counter, node, xslt_executable):
    # result_file = "threading-example/result-{}.xml".format(counter)
    # print('Transforming with file', 'to', result_file)

if xslt_executable is not None:
    transformedXML = xslt_executable.apply_templates_returning_string(xdm_value = node)
    sem.acquire()
    outputList.append(transformedXML)
    sem.release()
else:
    print(xslt30_processor.error_message)
'''sleep(randint(10,100))'''
'''saxon_proc.detach_current_thread'''



xmls = data.collect()

outputList = []
sem = threading.Semaphore()
with PySaxonProcessor(license = False) as saxon_proc:
    nodeList = [saxon_proc.parse_xml(xml_text=xml[0]) for xml in xmls]
    xslt30_processor = saxon_proc.new_xslt30_processor()
    xslt_executable = xslt30_processor.compile_stylesheet(stylesheet_text = stringxslt)
    if nodeList is None:
        print(saxon_proc.error_message)
        exit()
    # Create new threads
    thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1, nodeList[0],xslt_executable)
    thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2, nodeList[1],xslt_executable)
    thread3 = myThread(3, "Thread-3", 3, nodeList[2],xslt_executable)
    
    # Start new Threads
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()
    thread3.join()

    outputList
    print ("Exiting Main Thread")
```

Comment: In terms of Saxon, which Python package exactly do you use? The official SaxonC 12 package from Saxonica https://pypi.org/project/saxonche/ or some earlier package? As for parallel execution of XSLT 2 (or 3) with Saxon in Python, do you want to do that in a single Python program or in the context of that environment pyspark/databricks (I am afraid I am not familiar with)?

Comment: As for SaxonC 12 and its official package, there is one sample using multithreading and Python at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxonmirrorhe/repository/he/revisions/he_mirror_saxon_12_4_1/entry/src/main/c/pypi/samples/threading_test.py, perhaps that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I didn't know of the existence of such possibilities. I will try to see if that is applicable to pyspark aswell. My question being, this example processes the same file while i would like each thread to process different file would that still be possible ?

Comment: I would hope so, make sure you use https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc12/html/saxonc.html#PyXslt30Processor-compile_stylesheet to create PyXsltExecutable(s), they are supposed to be thread-safe.

Comment: Please research on Python's [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) and its `Pool`. Even I/O [`ThreadedPool`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor). Many StackOverflow questions have been asked and answered on these methods. Happy searching and then give it an earnest try!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, I have edited my question with reworked code using threads